# Shortcut connections in ResNet with different spatial sizes

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, residual-networks

If I take Fig.3 of the paper "Deep residual learning for image recognition", and look at the following piece of the residual network:

$3\times3$ conv, 64 filters

```
   | (X) (suppose shape is 14*14*64
   v
```

$3\times3$ conv, 128 filters, stride=2

```
   | (X') (shape will be 7*7*128
   v
```

$3\times3$ conv, 128 filters

```
   |
   v (F(X) (shape will be 7*7*128)
```

I thus must sum (element-wise) the result $X + F(X)$ which are of different shapes. However, while a $1\times1$ convolution can help to get the same depth (number of features), what is the traditional way to obtain the same width/height for both X and F(X)?

Should I compute MaxPooling(X, stride=2) + F(X)?

Answer (score 7):

The default way of solving this is to a 1x1 conv with a stride of 2, followed by a batch norm. Yes, half of the pixels will be ignored.

See the implemention in pytorch (from FAIR where the authors work): [link](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/fe973ceed96da733ec0ae61c525b2f886ccfba21/torchvision/models/resnet.py#L120-L127)

Answer (score 5):

I happened to read this paper recently. This paper introduced a shortcut projection to match the dimension. You can see equation 2 in the paper. Three different projection options A, B, C is compared in page 6.

There is a [tensorflow implementation of residual net](https://github.com/tensorflow/models). You can find implementation of shortcut projection in real code.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same issue. It looks like there are two ways to solve this: "When the input and output dimensions don’t match up, we add a convolutional layer in the shortcut path. The arrangement is called convolutional block" https://engmrk.com/residual-networks-resnets/